# Permutations and Divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

Here is a question that I'm working on:

> Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of the numbers $1,2,...,n$. The order of $\sigma$, given as $o(\sigma)$, is the *smallest* positive integer $m$ such that $$\sigma^m = Id$$
>
> Show that $o(\sigma)|n!$

**What I know:**
Well since I am given a permutation $\sigma$, this means that I can permute its elements a total of $n!$ ways. Then I would have to find the orders of each of the elements in my given permutation. Would [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) be helpful to proceed any further into the problem? If so, how would it be incorporated for this proof?

Comment: Yes, Lagrange's Theorem solves it.  Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\sigma$: that is, $H=\{\text{id},\sigma,\sigma^2,\ldots,\sigma^{m-1}\}$, where $m$ is the order of $\sigma$.  (You can prove, using $\sigma^m=\text{id}$, that this is a subgroup of the group of all permutations.)  Then $\lvert H\rvert=m$, and therefore $m$ must divide the order of the entire permutation group.

Comment: I like this approach Nick and lhf was able to do so without using Lagrange's Theorem. Both different, yet concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that does not need Lagrange's Theorem.

Every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles.
Therefore, the order of a permutation is the lcm of the orders of its disjoint cycles.
Since every cycle has order at most $n$, this lcm is a divisor of $1\cdot 2\cdots n = n!$.

Comment: I did not know one could go without using Lagrange's Theorem. Short and concise.